# Customize interface for org-capture-templates

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

Started using org-mode and I've gotten to configuring the org-capture template. Would like to get a simple set-up going for starters.

I've bound `'org-capture` to `C-c c` so `C-c c C` gives me the org-capture-templates interface - supposedly a good way to configure a template.

But how do I interact with this interface?

Consulted the org-manual but haven't found mention how how the customize interface actually work ...

Comment: The customize interface is part of Emacs itself, not Org specifically, and you can find help on it in the Emacs info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the customize buffer click on `INS` button it is just below the `Org Capture Templates` entry. This will open up a form like UI where you can fill the desired values. The explanation of what each value is given in the customize buffer itself. After you have entered the values save the template by clicking on `Apply and Save` button.

For general help on using the `customize` interface do <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>`Easy Customization Interface`<kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

I find that I have more control over my user customization file when I edit it manually, which lets me decide at what location entries are stored and I choose the format that suits my needs.  Always remember to keep daily backups just in case something goes awry.  The vast majority of examples that I generally see on the internet contemplate that the user will copy and paste the sample code into his / her user customization file, rather than using the built-in customization interface.

This is what I use for tasks, events, contacts, undated, etc.  I also use a modified version of `org-toodledo` and synchronize with the Toodledo server so that my hand-held devices and computers can all synchronize in the cloud:  https://github.com/christopherjwhite/org-toodledo

```lisp
(setq org-todo-keywords '(
  (sequence
  "Active(a)"
  "Next Action(n)"
  "Canceled(c)"
  "Hold(h)"
  "Reference(r)"
  "Delegated(d)"
  "Waiting(w)"
  "Postponed(P)"
  "Someday(s)"
  "Planning(p)"
  "|"
  "None(N)") ))

(setq org-capture-templates '(
  ("a" "Active" entry (file+headline "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.todo" "TASKS")
    "** Active [#A] %?\n   DEADLINE: <%<%Y-%m-%d %a>>\n   :PROPERTIES:\n   :ToodledoFolder: TASKS\n   :END:"
    :empty-lines 1)
  ("n" "Next Action" entry (file+headline "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.todo" "TASKS")
    "** Next Action [#A] %?\n   DEADLINE: <%<%Y-%m-%d %a>>\n   :PROPERTIES:\n   :ToodledoFolder: TASKS\n   :END:"
    :empty-lines 1)
  ("s" "Someday" entry (file+headline "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.todo" "UNDATED")
    "** Someday [#D] %?\n   :PROPERTIES:\n   :ToodledoFolder: UNDATED\n   :END:"
    :empty-lines 1)
  ("r" "Reference" entry (file+headline "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.todo" "EVENTS")
    "** Reference [#A] %? :event:\n   DEADLINE: <%<%Y-%m-%d %a 08:30>>  SCHEDULED: <%<%Y-%m-%d %a>>\n   :PROPERTIES:\n   :ToodledoFolder: EVENTS\n   :END:"
    :empty-lines 1)
  ("d" "Delegated" entry (file+headline "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.todo" "EVENTS")
    "** Delegated [#A] %? :event:\n   DEADLINE: <%<%Y-%m-%d %a 08:30>>  SCHEDULED: <%<%Y-%m-%d %a>>\n   :PROPERTIES:\n   :ToodledoFolder: EVENTS\n   :END:"
    :empty-lines 1)
  ("w" "Waiting" entry (file+headline "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.todo" "EVENTS")
    "** Waiting [#A] %? :event:\n   DEADLINE: <%<%Y-%m-%d %a 08:30>>  SCHEDULED: <%<%Y-%m-%d %a>>\n   :PROPERTIES:\n   :ToodledoFolder: EVENTS\n   :END:"
    :empty-lines 1)
  ("p" "Planning" entry (file+headline "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.todo" "CONTACTS")
    "** Planning [#D] %?\n   :PROPERTIES:\n   :ToodledoFolder: CONTACT\n   :END:"
    :empty-lines 1) ))
```

---

Here is what it looks like in practice:

---

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/gtd_example.png))</sub>

---

Here is screenshot of calendar entries containing `** Waiting`; `** Reference`; and `** Delegated`:

---

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [lawlist.com](http://www.lawlist.com/images/calendar_example.png))</sub>

Comment: This will be very helpful. The above answer addresses my question about the customize interface more specifically, though ...